# Wss4jSecurityInterceptor Library, It is responding to me with 202 Accepted but it does not respond to the response that I indicated

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, http-headers

I configured an interceptor to be able to accept the UserToken in the header of my request. It is a Soap that receives these parameters in the Header of the request that we are doing. Below I leave an image of the endpoint configuration[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaAcz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foP3c.png)

This is the response I always get, but the idea is that an object that I propose as a response responds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foP3c.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO - please add your code as text to your question, rather than as images - see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode